# Elasticsearch - search for substring spanning 2 words

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, search

#### Simple Example

I have a document with a `name` text field that typically contains addresses:

`1234 Palm Tree Street NE, Miami, FL 33101`

I would expect Elasticsearch to find the `Palm Tree` in the above address when I use `wildcard` with:

`*alm Tre*`

Instead, I get no results.

#### Rationale / realistic example

Sometimes the `name` field contains encoded information that spans 2 words, as follows:

`R3358b7119 x3387HRL388`

I'm using a wildcard with `*<search phrase>*`, which works when the user enters either 2 whole "words" or a single partial word. But, if the user enters the end of one word and the beginning of the next word, like `b7119 x3387` (using the example above) the document isn't returned.

#### Regexp doesn't seem to be a possible solution :(

I tried to use regexp search:

`{'regexp': {'name': '.*b7119 x3387.*'}}`

But even that did not return the document.

I'm truly at a loss...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all for regexp to work, you need to set mapping for your `name` with `not_analyzed` because Elasticsearch will apply the regexp to the **terms produced by the tokenizer** for that field, and **not to the original text** of the field

```
"type": {
   "properties": {
      "name": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed",
         "store": true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: mention not, glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not already aware, regexp with `.*` are computational expensive. A more elasticsearch way solution would be to use analyzers to handle your problem.

You can create a field without the whitespaces and use an [ngram analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to split your text into sub tokens. This solution should be much faster, but will require much more disk space to store all the subsets.